# What am I missing with the migration of my Wordpress Site from one Dreamhost Account to another?

Tags: wordpress, migration, dreamhost

I have spent at least 20 hours trying to figure this out at this point and just don't know what I am missing. I am moving a Wordpress site hosted on one Dreamhost Account to a different hosting account, but keeping the registration of the domain in the original account. Here are the steps that I have taken to accomplish this. As of now, it shows the "Site not Found" page via dreamhost. Any ideas would be GREATLY appreciated.

1. Backed up Website Files via FTP onto Local Computer.
2. Backed up sql file via phpmyadmin onto Local Computer.
3. (No attached emails, so didn't back this up.)
4. In Hosting account, added a new domain.dreamhosters.com temporary domain.
5. Added new database for domain.dreamhosters.com.
6. Uploaded sql file to the new database.
7. Uploaded domain.com website files to hosting account directory under temporary domain.dreamhosters.com and deleted the domain.dreamhosters.com file.
8. Updated wp-config file to connect to new database (DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST, DB_PASSWORD, and $table_prefix).
9. Search and replaced in terminal all domain.com urls in new folder to be domain.dreamhosters.com
10. In the Wordpress admin, changed the site url and wordpress url to domain.dreamhosters.com.
11. Updated the path configuration in Dreamhost's panel to reflect the new folder name where the website files are located.
12. Tested the website, worked great when domain.dreamhosters.com request was made.
13. In the registrar's account, updated the dns A Records for @ and www to the IP Address where the hosted website files are located. (Found by using nslookup domain.dreamhosters.com)
14. Changed the site url and wordpress url in the wordpress url back to the domain.com.
15. Search and replaced in terminal all urls in new folder to be domain.com.
16. Waited until the new DNS records were propagated (a whole day, just to be sure). Checked with nslookup for domain.com and it matched domain.dreamhosters.com.
17. Cleared browser cache, browser is updated.
18. Requested [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) and "Site not Found" nor is the SSL certificate working even though the SSL was working during the test in step 12.

So, can anyone help with ideas of where I am going wrong? I feel as though I have hit a wall. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are getting "site not found" the problem is not with wordpress, it is most likely DNS related

Comment: hmmm...if the subdomain is working but the domain isn't then have you checked that the domain directory and subdomain directory are the same location?

Comment: How did you do the testing in step 12?

Comment: Have you adjusted your WP database wp_options table?  I don't think this is necessary based on what you've said, but maybe there's something you have missed telling us.  https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214580498-Change-the-WordPress-Site-URL  See option 2 in link

Comment: Hi all! I contacted Dreamhost Support and they informed me that I missed the step of deleting the domain from the original hosting account (setting it to "Registration Only"). Everything was a breeze after that! Thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: @KatiePardee That's good, thanks for letting us know. We mark questions as solved here by adding an answer and accepting it (instead of modifying the subject), so please add your comment as an answer below and accept it when you can to let others know it's complete. Thanks!